# Best way to calculate several iterations with different parameters?

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

I am making a program that calculates what requirements need to be met in order to win an achievement from a game.

An achievement can have multiple levels, each with different requirements, and a player could have already fulfilled part of the requirements. So, for example:

Achievement A level 1 requires 10 rat tails

Achievement A level 2 requires 8 rat tails and 2 wolf tails

In order to get Achievement A level 2 a player would need a total of 18 rat tails and 2 wolf tails, but if he already has 5 rat tails I'd like the program to tell him he needs 13 rat tails and 2 wolf tails.

Therefore I am looking for a mathematical equation or programming method that can easily (maybe in a loop) calculate the requirements of each level and substract what the player already has, in other words some sort of a loop that calculates a different equation each time. The reason for that is that a player can choose which level he wants, so he can choose "Tell me what I need for level 1" or "Tell me what I need for level 10" and after his selection the program needs to do the total calculation, which I can do by hand like:

```
int wolftail, rattail;
int wolftailInv, rattailInv;
if (level == 1)
{
  wolftail = 0;
  rattail = 10 - rattailInv;
}

if (level == 2)
{
  wolftail = 2 - wolftailInv;
  rattail = 18 - rattailInv;
}
```

Or, in other words the mathematical equation for the total for level 2 would be (let's for a moment ignore what the player already has):

```
Level 2 = Level 1 + 2x wolftail + 8x rattail
Level 1 = 10x rattail
=>
Level 2 = 10x rattail + 2x wolftail + 8x rattail
```

while the equation for level 1 would be only:

```
Level 1 = 10x rattail
```

So I am wondering if there is a mathematical or programmatical method which could take into consideration the different mathematical equations for each separate level and automatically add them, but only the ones needed. In effect I am looking for the programmatical equivalent of substitution of the type:

```
x = 2y + apples
y = banana
=>
x = 2x banana + apples
```

This is a simple example, but the reason a simple sum won't work, because there are levels like this, also:

```
Level 6 = Level 5 + strangestuff
Level 5 = Level 4 + otherstuff
Level 4 = Level 3 + otherstuff
Level 3 = Level 2 + zzz
```

So the sum for Level 6 would be:

```
Level 6 = Level 2 + zzz + 2x otherstuff + strangestuff
```

But if a player already has Level 3 achieved the equation changes to:

```
Level 6 = 2x otherstuff + strangestuff
```

So I need mathematical substitution in c# and/or something that takes into account the different components that make a sum and can take them out, when needed.

Comment: We cant help you unless you show us how you represent your achievements, levels and players inventory in code. We need what you have tried so far as well.

Comment: If you don't even have any code that isn't working, there's no sense in already worrying about how to improve it. Correctness before almost anything else. Once you have code, it's much easier to take a look at it and see how it could be improved -- or even if it *should* be improved, in terms of clarity or performance. And if you can't write the code, tell us where the problem is so we can help.

Comment: Start with something. Do it dumb. Make it wrong. Experience problem. Find the reason. Fix it.

Comment: 18 - 5 = 13, simply subtract what the player has from what the player needs. What is the question here?

Comment: I would like to thank everyone who left a comment, I have edited the question and I hope that now it is clearer that I am looking for a design pattern and not help with a code error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So create each level as a list of items and amounts. For example:

```
enum ItemType
{
    RatTail,
    WolfTail,
    Stuff1,
    Stuff2
}

Dictionary<ItemType, int> Level1 = new Dictionary<ItemType, int>
{
    {RatTail, 10}
};

Dictionary<ItemType, int> Level2 = new Dictionary<ItemType, int>
{
    {RatTail, 18},
    {WolfTail, 2}
};

// Additional levels here
```

You'd then create a list or array of the levels:

```
List<Dictionary<ItemType, int>> Levels = new List<Dictionary<ItemType, int>>
{ Level1, Level2, Level3, ...};
```

The user's inventory is also stored in one of those dictionaries.

Each of the levels contains the *total cost* to achieve that level, not the incremental cost from the previous level. To determine how much it costs to get from Level X to Level Y, it's pretty simple:

```
For every item in Level Y
    Look up that item in Level X
    If the item exists in Level X then
        Subtract Level X count from Level Y count
        Add item and difference to Result
    Else
        Add item and Level Y count to Result
```

The result is the difference between Level Y (the target) and Level X.

Then, to figure out how much the player must earn, taking his current inventory into account, you do the same thing as above. For each item in Result, subtract the player's current count. The result is what the player must earn on top of what he currently has.

I would suggest putting the difference code into a loop, something like:

```
Dictionary<ItemType, int> ComputeLevelDifference(
    Dictionary<ItemType, int> CurrentLevel,
    Dictionary<ItemType, int> TargetLevel)
{
    // compute level difference here, and return
}
```

Then, to determine what a player must earn to get from one level to the next:

```
var LevelDifference = ComputeLevelDifference(CurrentLevel, TargetLevel);
var PlayerMustEarn = ComputeLevelDifference(PlayerInventory, LevelDifference);
```

The above assumes that when the player moves up a level, he "spends" the required items in his inventory. That is, if it takes 10 rat tails to get to Level 1, the player has to collect those rat tails, then spend them to advance to the level, so when he gets to Level 1 he has 0 rat tails in his inventory.

If the model is that he collects the rat tails and doesn't spend them, then you don't have to do the level difference. Instead you just compute the level difference using the player's current inventory and the target level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simpler approach could help:

As you already said, to get an achievement the player as to *pay* for it with some parts of his inventory. In that case, there should be some *inventory object* that is owned by the player object and contains all stuff he currently has. Now every achievement also has an inventory about the stuff that is needed to fulfill the achievement. Now you simply subtract every type within the achievement inventory with the amount of the same type within the player inventory and as a result you get an inventory that contains all the missing items that are needed to fulfill the achievement.

Comment: This is a good idea, but if the player wants, for example to see how much he will need to get a level 4 ach. and I substract what he has from level 4 and from level 3, while he alreay has level 3, there would be an extra "zzz" (from the example above). Meaning I would also need to manually put checks for every level and while I could do that I was hoping there would be some insane equation I could use, instead. :)